# Python 2.7 and Python 3.7 installed. How to use MadGraph with Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, operating-system

I am working with a simulation software MadGraph that is written in python. MadGraph is only compatible with python 2.7. My MadGraph is installed in /mnt/c/1 folder with Python 3.7.4 as I can see when I type ls in the /mnt/c/1 directory. But when I type in the /mnt/c/1 directory python --version I get python 2.7.15+. In /mnt/c/1MG5_aMC_v2_6_6 directory I type ls and I can't find python. When I type which python in the same directory I get /usr/bin/python. When I type ls bin I just get MadGraph and no python.

My question is how can I have python 2.7 working with MadGraph. I can work with MadGraph up to a certain point. When I want to type in a certain command in MadGraph I get this error:

```
Total: 4 processes with 4 diagrams
MG5_aMC>display diagrams
Drawing Process: u u~ > z > mu+ mu- WEIGHTED<=4 @1
Wrote file /tmp/diagrams_1_uux_z_mupmum.eps
open /tmp/diagrams_1_uux_z_mupmum.eps
Drawing Process: c c~ > z > mu+ mu- WEIGHTED<=4 @1
Wrote file /tmp/diagrams_1_ccx_z_mupmum.eps
open /tmp/diagrams_1_ccx_z_mupmum.eps
Drawing Process: d d~ > z > mu+ mu- WEIGHTED<=4 @1
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function call at 
0x7fbbb476bc08>Wrote file /tmp/diagrams_1_ddx_z_mupmum.eps

Traceback (most recent call last):
open /tmp/diagrams_1_ddx_z_mupmum.eps
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 172, in call
Drawing Process: s s~ > z > mu+ mu- WEIGHTED<=4 @1
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function call at 0x7fbbb476bc08>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 172, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
Wrote file /tmp/diagrams_1_ssx_z_mupmum.eps
open /tmp/diagrams_1_ssx_z_mupmum.eps
raise child_exception
time to draw 0.063835144043
raise child_exception
OSErrorOSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: [Errno 2] No such 
file or directory
MG5_aMC>
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function call at 0x7fbbb476bc08>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 172, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function call at 0x7fbbb476bc08>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 172, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I don't understand why I get this OS error for this certain command (of displaying the diagrams of the process that was simulated/generated). I can simulate the process fine but I can't display the diagrams. I end up with the error above and it gets stuck and I have to ctrl+c. I am wondering if it is because of the different python versions I have installed. I am just trying to understand this error written in python and how I can fix it. 
I would really appreciate some help. thanks!

Comment: Why do you think this is related to python 2 versus 3? Your trace back shows that the correct version of python (2.7) is used. It seems to be a bug in MadGraph's multithreaded drawing. Have you contacted the developers?

Comment: MisterMiyagi is correct - the traceback shows that MadGraph is using Python 2.7.  However, when you type a "command", MadGraph tries to [Popen()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) some other script or executable.  You're getting an "errno 2" exception: whatever script or executable MadGraph is trying to open, it can't find it in your current [PATH](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html).  SUGGESTION: try [strace](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-strace-command-examples.html).

Comment: Looks like it won't help you here, but some unsolicited advice for managing Python 2.7 alongside Python 3: use virtual environments. I recommend either [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) or [`conda`](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/). Speaking from experience: managing different Python installations without virtual environments will make you sad.

Answer (score 1):

MisterMiyagi is correct - the traceback shows that MadGraph is using Python 2.7.

However, when you type a "command", MadGraph tries to [Popen()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) some other script or executable.  You're getting an "errno 2" exception: whatever script or executable MadGraph is trying to open, it can't find it in your current [PATH](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html).

SUGGESTIONS:

1. Try [strace](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-strace-command-examples.html) to determine exactly what file Popen is trying to find.
2. Modify your PATH to include the directory this file is located in.

Please post back what you find.